# evento onclick en un spinner

Tags: java, android, android-studio, spinner, botón

estoy realizando un activity que utiliza un `spinner` para habilitar varias opciones pero dentro del `spinner` quiero poner un evento `onclick` para que se comunique con un boton en el activity y este realize una operacion.

Este es el codigo.

```
public class ejemolo extends AppCompatActivity {

    String[] Items = {
            "Dc amps a Kw",
            "Ac una fase amp a kw ",
            "Ac trifasica amps a kw (linia a linea de voltaje)",
            "Ac trifasica amps a kw (linia a voltaje neutral)",


    };

    Spinner s1;

    private String[] listOfObjects;


    EditText ampEditText , voltageEditText , powerfactorEditText  ;

    TextView text1 , text2 , text3, text4 ;

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ejemolo);




        FloatingActionButton buttonback = (FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.floatingActionButtonback);
        buttonback.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent  = new Intent(v.getContext() , Weight.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent ,0);
            }
        });


        FloatingActionButton buttonhome = (FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.floatingActionButtonhome);
        buttonhome.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent  = new Intent(v.getContext() , MainActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent ,0);
            }
        });



        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);


        s1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerAmp);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, Items);

        s1.setAdapter(adapter);


        ampEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ampEditText);
        voltageEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.voltageEditText);


        text1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.prueba1);
        text2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.prueba2);




        powerfactorEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.powerfactorEditText);



        //text1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tonsTextResult1);
        //text2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tonsTextResult2);


        listOfObjects = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.object_array4);

//        final Spinner spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinnerAmp);


        final android.icu.text.DecimalFormat decimals = new android.icu.text.DecimalFormat("0.00"); /** la cantidad de digitos decimales que se muestra */


       // ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, listOfObjects);




        s1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                switch (position) {


                    case 0 :



                            int indzex = s1.getSelectedItemPosition();


                        powerfactorEditText.setVisibility(View.GONE);



                        final  EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.voltageEditText);
                        final  EditText editText2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ampEditText);






                    case 1:



                           int index = s1.getSelectedItemPosition();


                        powerfactorEditText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);






                        break;

                }


            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });






    }





}
```

Comment: Un evento _onclick_ no funcionará con un _spinner_ , lo correcto sería como se ve en su código un _OnItemSelectedListener_

Comment: @Dev.Joel el problema que voy a tomar 3 valores de 3 editText  diferentes con diferentes problemas y necesito un spinner para la seleccion y un boton para lanzar el resultado

Comment: La selección de un elemento del _Spinner_ se realiza por medio de `OnItemSelectedListener` ya se brindó una respuesta sobre esto.

Comment: @Dev.Joel ya publique como lo hice con el mismo OnItemSelectedListener

Answer (score 3):

Este evento creo que puede ayudarte, si no he entendido mal lo que quieres es hacer cierta operación cuando selecciones algo en el spinner verdad?

En este ejemplo se muestra un simple Toast pero es cuestión de reemplaces dicho Toast por lo que quieras.

```
spnOpciones.setOnItemSelectedListener(
new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> spn,
                               android.view.View v,
                               int posicion,
                               long id) {
        Toast.makeText(spn.getContext(), "Has seleccionado " +
                       spn.getItemAtPosition(posicion).toString(),
                       Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> spn) {
    }
});
```

Comment: es mas o menos eso pero el toast no me funciona necesito mostrar el resultado en un textView

Comment: Que error te da? Si es así elimina el Toast y escribe: nombreTextView.setText(spn.getItemAtPosition(posicion).toString());

Comment: lo realice con el OnItemSelectedListener

Answer (score 0):

De esta forma pude hacer las dos cosas ocultar el `editText` y la operacion

```
@Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            switch (position) {


                case 0 :



                        int indzex = s1.getSelectedItemPosition();

                         powerfactorEditText.setVisibility(View.GONE);






                    ampEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                        @Override
                        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {


                            if (!(ampEditText.getText().toString()).isEmpty() && !(voltageEditText.getText().toString()).isEmpty() ){


                                double value = Double.parseDouble(ampEditText.getText().toString());
                                double value2= Double.parseDouble(voltageEditText.getText().toString());


                                double result = value * value2 ;


                                text1.setText(decimals.format(result));





                            }



                        }
                    });
```